# Finding running time of the following code

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
public static int loop(int n){
  int j = 1;
  int n2 = n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    n2 *= 5.0/7.0;
      for (int k = 0; k < n2; k++) {
        System.out.println("Hello.");
      }
    }
  return j;
}
```

Hello all, I'm having some difficulties figuring out the time complexity of the above code.

Here's what I have so far:

When i=0, inner loop is executed: (5/7) * n

When i=1, inner loop is executed: (5/7)^2 * n

...

When i=n, inner loop is executed: (5/7)^(n+1) * n

Summing them up, I get O(n * (5/7)^n). Is this an accurate analysis?

Comment: Sorry I realised I omitted the n term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion isn't correct; in fact, when 0 < r < 1 the formula n * r<sup>n</sup> converges to 0 as n tends to infinity, so it's definitely not an upper bound for the running time of an algorithm that does more than 0 things.

In your algorithm, r = 5/7, but for readability I'll keep writing r in this answer. The formula for summing these terms gives the result like n * r * (r<sup>n+1</sup> - 1)/(r - 1). The extra factor of r is because the sequence does not start at 1 * n. We need to be careful simplifying this formula, because for 0 < r < 1 the numerator and denominator of the fraction are both **negative**, and the dominant term in the numerator is 1, which dominates r<sup>n+1</sup> because the latter converges to 0 as n tends to infinity.

If we rewrite it as n * r * (1 - r<sup>n+1</sup>)/(1 - r) then it's clearer. Discarding the constant factors of r and 1/(1-r) we get O(n * (1 - r<sup>n+1</sup>)), and then discarding the dominated term -r<sup>n+1</sup> we get O(n * 1), or just O(n).

Another way of seeing this is that the sequence is bounded above by n * (r + r<sup>2</sup> + r<sup>3</sup> + ...), where the infinite series converges to the constant r/(1 - r), so it's bounded above by n times a constant.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out that I did have the full expression 5/2 * n * (1-r^(n+1)). Just that I erroneously dropped the (5/2)n term seeing that there's a term with exponential power. As a side note: are there algorithm with O(r^n), with r < 1?

Comment: Since algorithms have to perform an integer number of operations, the only integer less than a constant multiple of r^n for sufficiently large n is 0. So the algorithm would have to do 0 operations for all inputs, i.e. literally nothing; it couldn't even look at n and decide to do nothing for large n, since the comparison would take more than 0 operations.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you once again for all your help.